# Samsung Touchwiz lists widget

Tags: android, listview, samsung-mobile

I want the widget which is used in `Samsung Touchwiz UX`, in file manager, Music player, and some other apps, that two `ListView`s are in left and right side of the tablet, and there is a separator in middle of them which can change the widths of the left and right side `ListView`s when touched.

Where can I get this `View`, or, is there any suggested way to implement that?

thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made with Fragments and Fragment Activity! You can start reading Android documentation about "Building a Flexible UI" http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html and "Combining Multiple Views Into One" http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html#combining-views

It's good practic to always use fragments.